# How to add Google Pay and Apple Pay options to Stripe Checkout when session mode is "setup"?

Tags: stripe-payments, applepay, google-pay

How can I enable options for `Google Pay` and `Apple Pay` to appear in Stripe Checkout page when using Checkout Session with mode `setup`?

I'm trying to add a new payment method for a customer so I can later use it to charge for a subscription upgrade.

The issue is that I cannot figure out how to add these payment options to show on the checkout page and create a payment method for it.

If I change my Checkout Session to mode `subscription` the options show correctly and the payment method is created correctly, but this mode creates and charge a subscription which I don't want. I only want to add the payment method without charging anything.

Answer (score 0):

Using Google and Apple Pay for Checkout setup mode isn't possible. The point of "setup" mode is to collect payment details and perform a 3DS check on them so you can charge "off-session" later without having to get your user back "on-session" in case 3DS is required.

Apple and Google's wallets are considered exempt from 3DS since they already require a 2FA activation.

If you want to use a digital wallet to create a subscription but not charge till later, you should look into using [trial periods](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/trials).